# Is there a way to target android-29 by using cordova android@6.2.3?

Tags: android, cordova

I used minSDKversion as 15 in Cordova android@9. Meaning I changed the values of minSDKversion in build Gradle and other places. Then using aapt I also checked and it shows 15. But when I run the app in android phone it says: "unfortunately app has stopped". The in-play store we must target 28 now, Cordova also allows that. But Cordova android@9 does not allow minSDKversion 15 or even 21. Can anybody provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I want to use the android@9 with minSdkversion 19 and changing the values was not enough, the app crash.
Then I made a fork with the code removed to work with the android 5.

https://github.com/we-are-Joinup/cordova-android/tree/allow_sdk19_compatibility

I didn't test with minSdkversion 15 perhaps works, but this get you the idea to add the code removed in previous cordova-android versions.